# App client authentication (login) and CQRS

Tags: authentication, cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm interested in practical scenarios of authentication/login in web application when CQRS pattern is used to build the system.

Say we using HTTP services for commands/queries. And authentication with JWT (or any other authentication token)

- We send command `LogInUser` with credentials (HTTP request).
- Server command handler checks credentials, writes events in the store (if using Event Sourcing).

What then? What should we return as the result of the command? Just ok result with `authToken`? Then client should query the state in the read service? In this case we just make the whole process longer. And this concern actually refers not only to authentication scenarios but also other scenarios when we send a command and expect to get the result of it execution as soon as possible.

I just would like to hear from people who implemented such things. Want to understand possible practical data/requests flows for authentication using CQRS.

Comment: In my experience, the authentication part of an application rarely uses CQRS/ES. About commands returning results vs requerying after the command, there's an ever-raging dispute you'll easily find traces of here on SO.

Comment: Thanks, I get your point. Interesting to hear if somebody made alike solution or failed to make so

Comment: Either your api controller can poll/wait for the result, or the client can. Another approach is push based notifications to the client on another channel (e.g. websockets). One issue of returning read state directly is knowing what the client wants - the query api may be complex, and you might end up wasting time returning to the client insufficient or unnecessary data. There are other options such as including in the query API the ability to wait for a particular commands events to have been processed, so polling isn’t such an issue.

Comment: Ok thank I've been thinking alike a way.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using CQRS, you have decided to separate writing to the application from reading from the application.

- To write to the application, you use commands.
- To read from the application, you either wait for events, or you query the read model.

This diagram shows the relation between the different options:

[image: Architecture of a CQRS application]

(The diagram is taken from the documentation of [wolkenkit](https://docs.wolkenkit.io/1.2.0/getting-started/understanding-wolkenkit/architecture/), a CQRS and event-sourcing framework for JavaScript and Node.js.)

So, when you send your `LogInUser` command, the command itself does not return *anything* (of course, when using HTTP there *must* be a response, but it should just be a `200 OK`, so that you can verify that the server received the command and will care about it sooner or later).

Now the server process the login, verifies the sent credentials, and so on, and generates an appropriate `UserLoggedIn` event. This event gets stored in the event store, and is then sent to the read model.

The read model does two things with this event:

- It simply forwards it to the client.
- It updates any denormalized tables you may have that are interested in this event, so you can query them later.

So your client has two options:

1. It can wait for the event after having sent the command. Once the event is being received, the client has the JWT.
2. It can query the read model, until a given record was updated.

As you need to make sure that only the sender of the command is able to receive the JWT, option 1 is actually the only viable way. You can make sure that an event gets only delivered to the client that sent the appropriate command, but you can't have a table that contains all JWTs where people can only read *their* JWTs before being authenticated. With the read model, you have a chicken-and-egg problem here.

So, to cut a long story short: The client should wait for the appropriate event, and the event contains the JWT. That's it.

Comment: What should be the aggregate id in such case. we can have case where we supports login with different methods - means email, mobile both can be used for login. So how our aggregate should be designed here

Comment: Which aggregate do you mean?

Comment: If we create command loginUser -> then it should be handler by some writeModel and should have an aggregateId associated with it so that it can load snapshot. So what aggregateId should be used in this case

Comment: Are you trying to build your own authentication system?

Comment: sorry for replying too late. Yes we are trying to build own customized authentication system

Comment: You may model the aggregate for authentication as "users" or "user manager", it doesn't have to be a specific user aggregate per user account. This way the client doesn't need to specific the user id when login from email or phone.

Comment: `UserLogin` typically does not modify any data. For me it's  more like a Query operation, where you send credentials asking for a token as result.